# Writing a list of urls to a cell then writing pd.to_excel. List of URLs becomes one single url. How to avoid this?

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have a datframe with a list of urls in some cells.

```
list_of_urls = ['https://gradireland.com/institution/nui-galway/538605-paediatrics-research', 'http://www.nuigalway.ie/courses/research-postgraduate-programmes/structured-phd/bacteriology.html', 'http://www.nuigalway.ie/media/Visiting-Students-Academic-Handbook-Semester-1-17_18.pdf', 'http://www.nuigalway.ie/medicine-nursing-and-health-sciences/phd-and-masters/paediatrics.html', 'http://ncla.ie/courses/research-postgraduate-programmes/structured-phd/paediatrics.html', 'http://www.nuigalway.ie/courses/research-postgraduate-programmes/structured-phd/bacteriology.html']
```

I write them to the cells using `join`:

```
', '.join(list_of_urls)
```

Here's an example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Data': [', '.join(list_of_urls)]})

df.to_excel('test.xlsx')
```

It looks like panads /  excel is treating these as one long url, because sometimes I get a `max url` warning.

```
UserWarning: Ignoring URL

2079 characters since it exceeds Excel's limit for URLS

  (force_unicode(url), max_url))
```

Is there any way to save these urls into a single cell so excel / pandas treats them as separate urls rather than one?

Comment: which pandas version are you using?
Tried running the script on ubuntu with pandas 0.25.3 and it worked fine.

Comment: @AlonGoldenberg it is because the list of urls given is not long enough to reach the limit, try with `df = pd.DataFrame({'Data': [', '.join(list_of_urls*10)]})` and you'll see the error